# Loop all pages and get the first line with text

Tags: vba, loops, pdf, printing, ms-word

I would like to use VBA to loop the pages of my MS Word document and print each page as PDF separately. The name of each PDF file has to be the first line with text in each page. Im trying something along the lines of:

```
Sub printSepPdf()

        Dim pages As Page
        Dim p As Paragraph
        
    
    
        For Each pages In ActiveDocument
            ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=p.Range.Sentences(1) & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
            OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
            wdExportFromTo, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
            IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=False, CreateBookmarks:= _
            wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=False, UseISO19005_1:=False
    
    Next pages
    
     
    End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a document generated by a mailmerge, see *Split Merged Output to Separate Documents* or, better still, *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your code ... ActiveDocument doesn't actually have a reference to Pages directly ... you don't set Paragraph p anywhere ... page numbers are hardcoded in the export.

Try the following. It loops through each page of the document (noting that the document must be in PrintLayout view), then gets the first sentence, reduces that by 1 to remove the end-of-para character, and creates the PDF file name. Then it saves the entire page as a PDF.

```
Sub printSepPdf()

    Dim PageCounter As Long
    Dim PageFirstSentence As Range
    Dim PDFName As String
    
    For PageCounter = 1 To ActiveDocument.Windows(1).Panes(1).pages.Count
        Set PageFirstSentence = ActiveDocument.Range.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, PageCounter)
        PageFirstSentence.Expand (wdSentence)
        PageFirstSentence.SetRange PageFirstSentence.Start, PageFirstSentence.End - 1
        PDFName = PageFirstSentence & ".pdf"
        
        ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=PDFName, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, _
        OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportFromTo, _
        From:=PageCounter, _
        To:=PageCounter, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=False, _
        KeepIRM:=False, _
        CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, _
        DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=False, _
        UseISO19005_1:=False
        
    Next

End Sub
```